# What is the actual natural gas and electricity consumption of a Haber Bosch plant?

Tags: chemical-engineering

Plants running the Haber Bosch process provide the vast majority of nitrogen used in fertilizers. Collectivly, they consume about *[3–5% of the world's natural gas production [...] (around 1–2% of the world's annual energy supply)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber_process#Economic_and_environmental_aspects)*. Other sources stress that natural gas use accounts for roughly half the energy budget of these plants, the other half beeing electricity to run the turbocompressors. With casual googling, I only found numbers at the global level.

I want to have more exact numbers for the natural gas and energy consumption of a typical Haber Bosch plant, relative to the fertilizer output.

Comment: linked question https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42644/what-is-the-energy-and-capital-cost-of-nh3-from-haber-bosch-plant-that-takes-in