# What is the energy and capital cost of NH3 from Haber Bosch plant that takes in pure H2 and N2?

Tags: thermodynamics, chemical-engineering, cost-estimation

A question that becomes particularly relevant for "the hydrogen economy" or in the event that IGCC coal baseload electric generation seeks off-peak markets for hydrogen.

I can't seem to locate a breakdown of the costs of Haber Bosch plants adequate to tell me about just the Haber Bosch reaction stage of the plant*.

In particular, I'm interested in the energy consumed to and the capital cost per capacity.

*I did find [an IGCC conceptual design paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319219561_Conceptual_Design_and_Energy_Analysis_of_Integrated_Combined_Cycle_Gasification_System) that proposes a Haber Bosch stage consuming [375MW producing 8731kg/hr implying NH3 would cost 43,000kWh/tonne](https://www.calchemy.com/uclive.htm?375MW%3B8731kg/hr%3FkWh/tonne) but that seems quite exorbitant.  By contrast, there is [another proposal](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/84312607.pdf) that says [6MW is adequate to produce 1000tonne/day implying a cost of 144kWh/tonne](https://www.calchemy.com/uclive.htm?1000tonne/day%3B6MW%3FkWh/tonne).  An additional dataum is capital cost of 3000€/kgh ammonia capacity I located from [a slide presentation pdf](http://www.neocarbonenergy.fi/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/12_Ikaheimo.pdf) but it isn't clear whether this includes the air separation unit capital.

Comment: A significant r\part of the cost is making H, do you mean to ignore that cost ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 If you exchange the source of H2 from natural gas to something else, this question becomes relevant.

Comment: I added a motivating sentence at the beginning.

Comment: @mart so you are saying that without your suggested change, the question is not relevant?

Comment: Engineering implicitly is about relevance, so it would be redundant to say that the question "becomes relevant", hence the qualifier "particularly".

Comment: Now that I think of it, my problem with this question is not relevance but that we don't know your prior research. electric powered HB plants where developed at least as a concept as containerized units, a few years back I'd also seen research papers on these - so the energy part is probably answerable with an an hour or so on google scholar and sci hub (did you try that, @JamesBowery ?). Capital cost, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Well I spent several hours doing web searches without being able to find any papers that broke out just H2+N2 => NH3 stage from the electrolyitic and other energy inputs of unrelated stages (such as air separation units, etc.).  I could go back over those results and show you what I mean if you like.